# Need to check a GPU Crossfire compatibility

Tags: gpu, sli, crossfire

I couldn't think of a better place to ask this question. Basically I have an older gaming configuration, but I don't have the budget for a new one, and least I can do is to upgrade my GPU.

My current one is NVIDIA GeForce GTX550ti Windforce and I am thinking of buying another one and hook them in Crossfire / SLI.

However that GPU cannot be bought anymore so is there a place where I can find out which graphics cards are compatible for a Crossfire setup with the one i have?

Comment: Crossfire is proprietary to AMD, Nvidia uses SLI, which (mostly) matched cards. http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq

Comment: So I cannot add another GPU different from that one?

Comment: For Nvidia SLI: no, you cannot add an AMD/ATI card and expect it to speak SLI.  For DX12 setup this might sort of work though, but without SLI but with the DX build in functionality. Given the ages of your card, extra overhead for both SLI or crossfire and that older title need to explicitly support it is way more sensible to buy one more modern card.

Comment: Most people don't understand that SLI/Crossfire is built on the idea of, putting bunch of cards into a system, then making them appear as a single card and allowing software to handle the work distribution.  DX12 allows for multiple independant cards to perform a function.  One allows for GPU calcuations to be parallelized the other one does not (SLI/Crossfire)

Answer (score 3):

Crossfire/SLI is only usable with two of the "same card". That is, a GTX 550 TI with any other GTX 550 TI. The brand or manufacturer is not important to this (but can help for optimal performance). Keep in mind that you will be pegged to the maximum VRAM of the lesser card; for example, using SLI between a 1GB card and a 2GB card will net you a total usable VRAM of 1GB.

Most especially with older hardware, the gain you will make by adding a second card will hardly be noticeable. With patience and a keen eye you can likely find a used GTX 960 for close to $100. This will be unimaginably more powerful than two 550 TI in SLI.

Comment: Crossfire will work with different cards as long as the GPU family is the same. Allows things like crossfire between an APU and a dedicated graphics card.  +1 for the second paragraph though.

Comment: As both of you suggested, I guess I am much better off with a new GPU ..